Row_Number(), Offset, Fetch_Next and Restarting Numbering
I have the following

A pageheader table
A pagecontent table
An items table

I have a loop that creates a header record in the pageheader, and then a separate insert takes the next 25 records from the items table and inserts into the pagecontent table.
The next iteration of the loop has to reset the the numbering for the itemnumber in the pagecontent table.
This mostly all works, what I cannot get to work is the numbering to reset.
This is the data for the page content that I want to be created.



RowID
Header ID
Item Number
Item Code




1
1
1
00010


2
1
2
01002


3
1
3
01612


...
...
...
...


25
1
25
01701


26
2
1
00421



A simplified insert
( RowID
, HeaderID
, ItemID
, ItemCode
)
SELECT 
 ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY RowID) + (SELECT ISNULL(MAX(RowID), 0) FROM pagecontent) 
,@headerid
,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY RECORDID)
,ITEMCODE
FROM ITEMS
ORDER BY ITEMCODE
OFFSET @start ROWS
FETCH NEXT 25 ROWS ONLY;

Because the ROW_NUMBER IS numbering all the rows in ITEMS, before the FETCH NEXT is working.  I'M getting for RowID 26,  ItemID 26, when I want ItemID to be 1 as a new page has started.
Is there a way to reset the numbering, or would running an UPDATE to renumber afterwards?
I have currently resorted to running an UPDATE to correct.
I have just realized while writing this I could use a CASE and if the offset is greater than zero to subtract the offset from the number.
Thanks.

"I have a loop" why do you need a loop? And how about you show us all your code.

If @start is zero why can't you subtract it? Or use modulus to limit the values?

What does this have to do with regex?

If you have solved your problem, you can either (a) delete your question; or (b) if you think it will be useful to others, add a self-answer

The easy solution is to put the main query in a CTE or subquery and use ROW_NUMBER() in the outer query. No need to reset anything

Sorry, I hadn't realized I had put a regex tag in there.
I still posted to see if there was a better solution, I've modified the script to use a CTE and that works brilliantly.  Thanks @PanagiotisKanavos for the suggestion.
I didn't post the whole code as I was trying to keep it to the relevant bit to keep it short.

I have switched to using the following CTE
WITH ROWNUMBERING(RowID, HeaderID, ItemID, ItemCode) AS (

SELECT 
 ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY RowID) + (SELECT ISNULL(MAX(RowID), 0) FROM pagecontent) 
,@headerid
,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY RECORDID)
,ITEMCODE
FROM ITEMS
ORDER BY ITEMCODE
OFFSET @start ROWS
FETCH NEXT 25 ROWS ONLY
)
INSERT INTO PageContent
( RowID
, HeaderID
, ItemID
, ItemCode
)
SELECT RowID
,HeaderID
,ItemID
,ItemCode
FROM ROWNUMBERING

This works as intended.
